# Chat room owner should be able to change the room's associated SE site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, area-51

I propose that a chatroom owner should be able to change the chatroom's associated SE site. I recently created a chatroom to promote the [Korean Language proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language?referrer=_bGLWL4a0nyN5qIsOP5VxA2) at

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30769/korean-language-discussion-room-commit-stage

Somehow it got associated with TeX.SE and it turns out that I cannot do anything about it once the room is created

Since this chatroom was for promotion of an Area51 proposal I think it would be better suited being associated with Travel.SE or Linguistics.SE, possibly even Chinese.SE and Japanese.SE

Other features that would be nice to have:

- Associate a chatroom with more than one SE to give it more visibility
- a more intuitive user interface in the chatroom creation page

Comment: You can do anything about it: Flag for a moderator and have them change the association. I don't know how often this needs to be done and as creating chatrooms is not rate limited it is easy enough to create a new, correctly associated room. Not sure if dev capacity needs to be spend on this in the next 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: it's possible to flag a chatroom for moderator attention?

Comment: Yes, you can flag a message in the said room for moderator attention

Comment: ok thanks I'll try that as well

Answer (score 13):

As a moderator I have actually kicked rooms off my site a couple times -- people were having a conversation that wasn't in accord with our site's values and I did not want that room popping up for anybody who clicked "chat" from the main site.  Rather than outright deleting the room I sent them somewhere else, but if they could keep coming back I'd have to delete.

I can see this proposed feature being used to troll sites -- make a room somewhere and then migrate it to a site where it won't be welcome.  Given the other types of trolling we sometimes see in chat, I don't think this concern is unfounded.

Maybe it should be possible for a room owner to make a chat room *unparented* (not associated with any site).  That solves the "in the wrong place" part of the problem.  But if you want to move a room onto another site, I think you should need approval from the custodians of that site.

Meanwhile, you can always ask a moderator (via ping or flag) to reparent a room.  If the reason is clearly explained and unobjectionable, that should solve your problem.